# What is difference between Mix_Init and Mix_OpenAudio SDL?

Tags: c++, audio, sdl, sdl-2, sdl-mixer

I've seen many tutorials for SDL_mixer but none of them use the Mix_Init function. I saw this Mix_Init function on the documentation page:
https://web.archive.org/web/20210615233017/https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer.html

The tutorials only used a function called Mix_OpenAudio for initializing SDL_mixer.

If I call the function Mix_OpenAudio, will it automatically call the function Mix_Init? Is Mix_Init function is only some type of checker function?

Answer (score 2):

Check the documentation at https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer_9.html :

> Initialize by loading support as indicated by the flags, or at least
> return success if support is already loaded. You may call this
> multiple times, which will actually require you to call Mix_Quit just
> once to clean up. You may call this function with a 0 to retrieve
> whether support was built-in or not loaded yet.

If you need support for compressed audio formats like flac, mp3, ogg vorbis - you need to call this function with list of formats you need. I'll result in loading required code to decompress that formats, if it isn't built into SDL_mixer. If you only use WAV you may omit `Mix_Init` call.